# Large iframe height causing anchor tags to not work?

Tags: html, iframe

We have an ASP app that's sitting in an iframe on a page which creates a phone directory of our employees. You can see it here:

http://www.cecil.edu/Directory/

The iframe this is sitting in is set to 6350px high. When you click on a letter link in the alphabet, it's supposed to jump down to that letter on the page. It only seems to work properly in Chrome and Safari. No dice with IE 7/8/9 or Firefox.

This used to work fine before, at least in IE8, but stopped working at some point. Doing some fiddling, I found that the anchor tags would work if I dropped the height of the iframe down to around 4000px. But anything above that makes them either behave oddly by taking you to the wrong position on the page or not working at all.

Does anyone have knowledge of large iframe heights causing weird behavior like this? I can't seem to find any reference to it anywhere online.

Comment: Okay, after playing with this some more, here is what's happening: the iframe is bottoming out. So lets say I set it to 5000px high. I can click the letters in the alphabet and those anchors will work up to a certain point (in the case of 5000px, it stops working at 'E'). But once the scroll bar of the iframe reaches the bottom, anchors stop working. So IE/Firefox think that position is already being displayed when it's actually off-screen. Chrome/Safari handle this correctly. Seeing as how this is a problem at the browser level, I'm thinking there's no way to work around it.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I see your website is working now with "M" letter. I'm having a similar issue. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. I see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.scrollIntoView to the rescue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When IE uses Direct-X to render objects (such as when using css filter:), no dimension can be larger than 4906 pixels in any axis, due to the max size of a 12-bit register. While this *may* be an explanation for the limit in IE, it does not explain the limit in Firefox.

See: [IE display transparency bug on height > 4096px?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775041/ie-display-transparency-bug-on-height-4096px)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After looking at this though, this isn't the issue. But through your suggestion, I did find out what is happening. Adding a comment above with details...